# Find index of second and third largest items in a list

Tags: c#, list

For example I have a list like:

```
List<double> Nums = new List<double> {12.32, 5.12, 7.64, 9.77, 4.98, 8};
```

How can I find the index of the second and third highest double in the list?
The result would be giving 3 (for 9.77) and 5 (for 8).

It's important that the order of the values don't change. The rest of my code depends on the order of the list to not change.

Thanks!

Comment: Using LINQ, and assuming there are no duplicates, second highest would be `Nums.IndexOf(Nums.OrderByDescending(n => n).Skip(1).First());` and third would be `Nums.IndexOf(Nums.OrderByDescending(n => n).Skip(2).First());`. If there are multiple of the same, it will return index of the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
var numbers = Nums.OrderByDescending(x => x).Skip(1).Take(2); // this will get collection of second and third highest element
var secondHighestIndex = Nums.FindIndex(x => x == numbers.First()); // will get second highest index
var thirdHighestIndex = Nums.FindIndex(x => x == numbers.Last());// will get third highest index
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
 List<double> Nums = new List<double> { 12.32, 5.12, 7.64, 9.77, 4.98, 8 };
 var lst = Nums.Select((a, b) => new KeyValuePair<int, double>(b, a))
                      .OrderByDescending(c => c.Value).Skip(1).Take(2).ToList();
```

I created keyvalue pairs, using its value as value, and index as key. Then order it by its value, then skip the first result then take 2 results.

The resulting pair would be:

```
[0] {[3, 9.77]} 
[1] {[5, 8]}
```

You can access it via its index:

```
lst[0].Key; //For Index - 3 
lst[0].Value; //For Value - 9.77
```

Comment: That is a *very* useful overload on `Select` that I didn't know about.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq, as described in [@Keyur PATEL's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334112/c-sharp-finding-index-of-second-and-third-highest-of-items-in-a-list#comment79628880_46334112). A slight modification could get you both numbers in one statement: `Nums.OrderByDescending(n => n).Skip(1).Take(2);`

See [@Akash KC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334183/1253136)'s answer.

---

Another solution would be to traverse the array, comparing each element to the highest found, and saving the indexes of the 3 highest numbers as a limited-length stack, and simply ignore the highest after that's done:

```
var highest = Nums[0];
var topIndexes = new int[3];
for(int i=1; i<Nums.length; i++){
    if(Nums[i]>highest){
        topIndexes [2] = topIndexes [1]; //Record index of 3rd highest
        topIndexes [1] = topIndexes [0]; //Record index of 2nd highest
        topIndexes [0] = i; //Record index of highest
        highest = Nums[i];
    }
}
//Do something with topIndexes[1] (2nd highest number's index)
//and topIndexes[2] (3rd highest number's index)
```

The code above can easily be modified into a function/method useful for finding or taking the top `n` numbers or `n` indexes out of collections dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In step by step solution

```
List<double> Nums = new List<double> { 12.32, 5.12, 7.64, 9.77, 4.98, 8 };
var SMax = Nums.OrderByDescending(z => z).Skip(1).First();
var Tmax = Nums.OrderByDescending(z => z).Skip(2).First();
var SIndex = Nums.IndexOf(SMax);
var TIndex = Nums.IndexOf(Tmax);
```

Comment: I believe,ordering same list twice would not be recommended way

Comment: No it's just that I have added in steps